# In MVC, during POST, how do I loop through a list of model objects in the modelstate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Using MVC, I have a view model containing a list of model type 'claim'. On submit, if there is a server-side validation error causing Model.IsValid to be false, I need to show the errors, per claim, on a confirmation screen.

[image]

Is there a way to iterate through the rows of a list in the modelstate and find which row failed validation rather than every single modelstate key / value? I can see that validation failed for a value of $1000 below, but am not sure how to know which claim name / overall row it belongs to.

```
ClaimList[0].Name             Basket Weaving
ClaimList[0].Total            50
ClaimList[1].Name             Car Wash
ClaimList[1].Total            1000
```

I'm currently able to get the key name, value and error exception with the following:

```
foreach (var key in ViewData.ModelState.Keys)
{
    var modelStateVal    = ViewData.ModelState[key];
    var currentKeyValue  = ModelState[key].Value.AttemptedValue;

    foreach (var error in modelStateVal.Errors)
    {
        Utility.Log(key + ": " + currentKeyValue);
        Utility.Log(error.Exception);
    }
}
```

I'll be glad to give more details if this is not clear enough.

Comment: The indexer tells you which 'row' it is

Comment: How do I loop through them? Can I access a different field in the same 'row' (I'm aware it's an array) while looping?

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean - you are already loop through them (as a side note, I use `var errors = ModelState.Keys.Where(k => ModelState[k].Errors.Count > 0).Select(k => new { propertyName = k, errorMessage = ModelState[k].Errors[0].ErrorMessage });` to do the same thing